# How to simulate simultaneous web request on asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, testing, webrequest

I want to test my website's performance when many users are requesting my pages. Is there any way to simulate many requests? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate:

[Walkthrough: Creating and Running a Load Test Containing Web Performance Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx)

[Load Testing with Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/07/08/load-testing-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For my previous job, I had to test the performance of our asp.net webservices and what I did was wrote a simple `WinForm` application with multithreading and every thread make a request to my webservice using `HttpWebRequest`. 
You may have to increase the limit for concurrent requests on IIS, which as far as i know is 2 by default.